# If Aurala ir'Wynarn would die, who of the Wynarn bloodline would succeed her?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, eberron

If Aurala ir'Wynarn would die, who of the Wynarn bloodline would succeed her? If no particular successor can be singled out, how would succession naturally occur?

I'm looking for 5e answers, but I'm also interested in non-5e answers if no particular successor can be singled out to understand the process behind the succession of the Wynarn bloodline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Wrogar ir'Wynarn

Assuming the line of succession was properly followed. (Not the original Wrogar who was part of kicking off The Last War...Aurala has a son named after the original)

We have no details on this in 5E sources, so we have to look further back. This takes us to [Dungeon Magazine #170](https://archive.org/details/Dungeon_Magazine_170/page/n61/mode/2up) where we get the following blurb

> Prince Consort Sasik d'Vadalis, whom the queen's supporters claim she married for love, lives in Fairhold with the queen and two of her children. One of these children is Crown Prince Wrogar, who is a proper young man and stands to inherit the throne.

Further in that sidebar, we get that Aurala's youngest of three children (Princess Corrine) is a teenager--so we know that Price Wrogar (referred to as a Young Man) is most likely an adult or not far from it.

The main hangup we may run into here is that Aurala's brother (child 2 of 3--Aurala is the oldest) wants the throne. From the 3.5E Eberron Campaign Setting (page 138) we get the following:

> Aurala’s brother Adal serves as her warlord and minister of magic, and he shares her desire to see the Galifar crown on the head of an Aundair lord. He wants that head to be his, though, and not his sister’s.

So...if Aurala suddenly dies, Adal may attempt to make his move to try to bump Wrogar off succession and seize the throne for himself.

#### Sourcing Addendum

The reason I went straight back to older editions is because the 5E Eberron content tells us to do so for extra lore. [Appendix A](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wgte/further-reading) of the Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron says...

> After reading this Wayfinder’s Guide, you may have questions. What’s the Aurum? Who are the Daughters of Sora Kell? Just how many districts are there in Sharn, and what happens to adventurers in the Mournland? What’s in Xen’drik? Until new material becomes available for the fifth edition of the Dungeons & Dragons Roleplaying Game, you can find the answers to these questions and many more in the resources created in previous editions of the game.